# Flutter : How to align TextField with other widgets in row

Tags: flutter

I have a row with a Text () and a TextField ()
But they don't seem to align
I'm an Android Developer and my past experience seems to have no effect.
Do you have any suggestions for Android developers in terms of alignment skills?

[image: screenshot]

```
  SizedBox(
                          height:44,
                          child:
                          Row(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[
                            Text("+60",
                              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15,
                            color: Colors.white
                            ),),
                            Container(margin:EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15,0,15,0)
                            ,width: 1,height: 12,color: Color(0x33FFFFFF),),
                              Expanded(//TextField
                                child: TextField(
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                  cursorColor: Color(0x66FFFFFF),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize:15
                                  ),
                                  inputFormatters: [
                                    WhitelistingTextInputFormatter
                                        .digitsOnly,
                                    LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10)
                                  ],
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      hintText: 'Phone number',
                                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                          color: Color(0x66FFFFFF),
                                          fontSize: 15
                                      ),
                                      border: InputBorder.none
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
                                ,
                          ],)
                        )
```

Comment: What's the issue with the current result?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore TextField is lower

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `SizedBox` `height` property is controlling the `Row` constraint thus it's not allowing it to align it's childern freely, just remove the `SizedBox` widget and everything will work fine.